# Redirecting users after login through remember_me to different routes depending on their ROLES in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am trying to redirect my users to different routes depending on their ROLES when they login. It works fine within my `LoginFormAuthenticator` (`onAuthenticationSuccess` function), but not once the used has `remember_me` activated.

**LoginFormAuthenticator.php**

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    $roles = $token->getRoleNames();
    if (in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $roles, true)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('admin'));
    }

    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('homepage'));
}
```

**security.yaml**

```
remember_me:
    secret: '%kernel.secret%'
    lifetime: 604800  # 1 week in seconds
```

I manage to see that the `authenticate` function of the `RememberMeListener` is called at every request, but he first line of the function is checking for the **current security token** and if the request has one, it just ends the function with a `return;`. 
In my case, when I try to access the app through `remember_me`, there is a token. So I guess this is why I can use the `security.interactive_login` event that is dispatched a few lines below in this Listener.

**RememberMeListener.php**

```
public function authenticate(RequestEvent $event)
{
    if (null !== $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
        return;
    }

    (...)

    try {
        (...)

        if (null !== $this->dispatcher) {
            $loginEvent = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
            $this->dispatcher->dispatch($loginEvent, SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN);
        }

        (...)
    }
}
```

It is hard to find what other event I could use, so if anybody has a clue, I would be glad to try something else!